# Odometry heading and laser scan heading not point to same direction

Tags: ros, slam, odometry

please help, after so much research still cant find a single solution from google.
some say offset, but there is no offset in the configuration.

problem: odom direction and laser scan heading didnt match

let say the grid with x,y line
positive y is 0 degree and 
positive x is 90 degree

im using gmapping to do slam, 
and after running gmapping what i get was
the laser scan is facing to 0 degree while 
my odom is facing to 90 degree in rviz

i had try to find a solution or similar problem.. but seem there is none like this case out there.

so how can i rotate my odom to match my laser scan?

Answer (score 1):

[Ros tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf) will solve your problem. In your case, you can use a static tf in which the translation vector is zero and a 90-degree Rotation matrix.